# this.transformer.anchorSize is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, konvajs

I was trying to make some changes in Transformer Component in React Konva and faced this error whenever I was trying to change anchor size. I followed the syntax as stated in document - https://konvajs.github.io/api/Konva.Transformer.html#validateAnchors__anchor

The issue is in anchorSize. Please help me. Here's the code -

```
class TransformerComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    this.checkNode ();
  }

  componentDidUpdate () {
    this.checkNode ();
  }

  checkNode() {
    const stage = this.transformer.getStage();
    const { selectedShapeName } = this.props;
    const selectedNode = stage.findOne ('.' + selectedShapeName);

    this.transformer.rotateEnabled (false);
    this.transformer.anchorSize (5);

    if (selectedNode === this.transformer.node()) {
      return;
    }

    if (selectedNode) {
      this.transformer.attachTo (selectedNode);
    }
    else {
      this.transformer.detach();
    }

    this.transformer.getLayer().batchDraw();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Transformer
        ref = {node => {
          this.transformer = node;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`anchorSize` is a very new property introduces recently. Try to update `Konva` to the latest version.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again for help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **bind** *this* for `checkNode()` as down below:

```
class TransformerComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.checkNode = this.checkNode.bind(this)
    }
    ...
```

Comment: This is not the issue and its working fine if I don't use that anchorSize statement